# file path of BiocManager:install()

Tags: r, bioconductor, reference-genome

I was trying to format my GWAS summary statistics with the `MungeSumstats` R package and would need to install `SNPlocs.Hsapiens.dbSNP155.GRCh37` and `BSgenome.Hsapiens.1000genomes.hs37d5` as reference panel. 
I typed
`BiocManager::install("SNPlocs.Hsapiens.dbSNP144.GRCh37") BiocManager::install("BSgenome.Hsapiens.1000genomes.hs37d5")`
but failed due to Internet connection problems. So I planned to download the files from the web browser and copy them to the R library. I was wondering where I should put the files. If they were downloaded from R, where would they be saved? 
I would really appreciate any answers, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**First, I would try again to download via the bioconductor command. If your internet is intermittent it may just take a few tries.**

If that doesn't work, I would then strongly recommend using `BioCManager` [to install from a local source](https://www.biostars.org/p/157366/) wherever you've downloaded the files. If you try to copy the files around there are a lot of ways that things can go wrong, and there are a lot of ways that it still might not work even if you put it in the right place, if you don't use the package manager as intended.

Comment: Great thanks! I have tried unzipping the `.tar.gz` file and copying it, and things indeed went wrong. Like mentioned, installing from local sources seemed to be the best way.